# Unable to connect to Tridion Core Service from an Android client

Tags: android, tridion, tridion-2011

I am developing an Android app for connecting to Tridion 2011 SP1 Core Service. 
So far I have created Android WS Stubs from the core service wsdl using wsclient.

Imported those stubs, which allow access to all the core service methods.

I can now authenticate to Tridion via the Android application but as soon as I try to perform even the most basic of web service calls, such as `getApiVersion()`, I get the error:

> ReflectionHelper*java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: GetApiVersionResult.

I was wondering has anyone else managed to create a java android app that communicates with the Core Service?

Interestingly enough, if I run the code as a java application, using wsimport stubs everything works a treat.

Any help appreciated. For reference here is a code snippet:

To connect to Tridion:

```
class TridionConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { 
  // Called to initiate the background activity

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... statuses) {  
    try {
      Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
          return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
        }
      });

      url = new URL("http://tridion-server/webservices/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl");

      System.out.println(String.format("Get Service"));
      service = new CoreService2011();
      System.out.println(String.format("Get Client"));

      client = service.getBasicHttp();

      return "Authenticated To Tridion";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Authentication failure", e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "Failed to authenticate";
    }
  }

  // Called when there's a status to be updated
  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    // Not used in this case
  }

  // Called once the background activity has completed
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) { // 
    Toast.makeText(FullscreenActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    area.setText("Authenticated to Tridion OK");
  }
}
```

To get the ApiVersion

```
client.getApiVersion();
UserData currentUser = client.getCurrentUser();
System.out.println(String.format("'%s' %s", currentUser.getTitle(), currentUser.getId()));
```

Comment: Hi Allan, in general it is best to pass the entire exception to `Log.e` and not just the `toString`: `Log.e("TridionConnect", "Authentication Failure", e);`

Comment: I just see that you already said the code works fine in a regular program. In that case, it may be a difference between the real JVM/JRE and Dalvik. But without reproducing your problem, I can't be sure.

Comment: I am now coming to the conclusion that this is not possible as described above. I have an alternative solution which I am now investigating.

Comment: Did you also find out **why** it isn't possible. That might be helpful if someone in the future wants to try the same, since... things change. Btw: I completely forgot to say earlier, but I've had no problems connecting to Tridion Content Delivery (OData) service from an Android client. It makes a great use-case for consuming web content in a native app.

Comment: Nice question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frank,

It is not possible for a couple of reasons.

If you use wsimport to create the coreservice proxy it will use the javax library, which exists in the JRE. However Dalvik implements only a subset of the javax library which means this approach is impossible in the Android environment.

I then looked at Ksoap2 tools for creating the proxy. This seemed to work OK, in as much as it did create a proxy, however it did not match the coreservice so I was unable to authenticate. I didn't get any further with this approach beyond examining the JRE proxy v Ksoap2 proxy. They were quite different.

At this point I took a step back, had a cup of tea and re-engineered the approach.

I created a c# REST service to sit between the android app and the core service.

This approach seemed a bit complex, but it offers lots of advantages. Lots of the spade work can be done in the REST service, which will be much quicker than similar code on a tablet or phone.

Secondly the REST service sits on the same server as the CMS/CoreService so the comms is quicker and you can make the REST requests from the android app much lighter.

I have got the application to the point where you can authenticate to Tridion, select a publication, and components that is then rendered in a dynamic layout ready for update/save/publish.

The one big downside of this approach is that the REST service 'should' be stateless so superficially you have to authenticate to the coreservice for every request. Of course I don't do that, but you have to come up with some alternative approach Oauth, shared secret etc.

In initial tests this approach has seemed to be fairly slick on an android device.

Comment: Hi Bart, I committed to the area 51 proposal. I started Tridion development when we were at version 5.1 and the only resource was the tridion forums and the support department. It's high time we had a publicly available resource for all things Tridion.

Comment: Both comments above from Josanne Kane, are in fact from me.... My wife quite obviously used my laptop. As an aside, don't take any of her advice unless it concerns baking!